# Consuming JSON Web Data into a Class Array in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm having a few problems trying to consume my JSON Data from a web URL and put it into my Class Array.

My class looks something like this;

```
public class User
{
     String Name;
     String Serial;
     String Email;
}
```

Where my JSON data looks like

```
{ "name": "cname", "value": [ "Joe Bloggs"] },
{ "name": "serialnumber", "value": [ "231212312" ] },
{ "name": "gender", "value": [ "male" ] },
{ "name": "email", "value": [ "jbloggs@domain.com" ] },
```

I want to pop this into a User Class Array so that it would be somthing like

```
User myUsers[] = new User[100];
```

I have the data downloaded using a StreamReader, but I'm lost as to where to start. I've tried out DataContractJsonSerializer and a few others but can't find any basic guides on the web where to start.

I should note that I want to only grab the values listed in the class and not extras such as Gender etc.

If someone could provide a basic sample of both the class and the program implementation to read the data that would be great.

Thanks,

CM888.

Comment: Curious, why are all your values single entry arrays? Are they where the different users are? I.e. `{"name":"cname", "value": ["Joe", "Bob"]}` would represent 2 different users?

Comment: Ahh looking at the DB everyone starts with Name first then the Attribute the value

Comment: I've expanded my question from the comments in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I **Highly** Reccomend looking into this library:

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

It has many great features, but the best is that it's designed to mimic LINQ to XML. You can use it very similarly.

Using this library you could parse your json into objects and work with them & linq queries to build up your user array.

---

*To expand on my comment above: (Unrelated to question or answer)*

What i meant was i was curious why your JSON wasn't strctured like this:

```
[
  {"cname": "Joe Bloggs", "serialnumber": "231313213", "gender": "male", "email": "jbloggs@domain.com"},
  {"cname": "Another Dude", "serialnumber": "345345345", "gender": "male", "email": "another@dude.com"}
]
```